# How to turn off "Warn me if iTunes is not the default player for audio files."

Tags: windows-7, itunes

If I go into my iTunes settings, in Advanced there is an option for “Warn me if iTunes is not the default player for audio files.”

I unchecked this and clicked OK. If I go back into iTunes settings, it is checked again.

Is there a way to actually turn this off? I'm tired of it asking every time I open iTunes.

Comment: I'm assuming Windows, as Mac doesn't have that checkbox in Advanced.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, added relevant OS tag.

Comment: This is so annoying. I can't believe something this simple doesn't work.